# Did they end up going to the café first or straight to the library after the film according to the following dialogue?

Tags: conversation

M:  I’ve got the cinema tickets. The film’s at 2:30 this afternoon and lasts about two hours. We could have a hot chocolate at the cafe after it.

W:  That’d be nice, but I’ve got to get some information for my school project before I go home.

M:  I’ll come and help you in the library if you want. I want to return a CD to the music shop but I could come back tomorrow to do that.

W:  OK.

Comment: No information that says the library isn’t after the movie and before the cafe. Or maybe they both know that W needs to go home before the movie and therefore the library is before the movie and cafe.

Comment: With the film finishing about 4:30 (2:30 + 2 hours) and W being at school rather than college or work it's unlikely that they would have time to vist both the library and the cafe. Having said that there is insufficient information to be sure and the answer isn't dependent on the language but on logic and deduction. I've voted to close this question as being opinion-based rzther than language-bzsed.

Comment: Without further context, the role of *but* in W's utterance is unclear: it could be that what follows it is a reason against going to the cafe, or it could be that it is just a limit on how long they can stay in the cafe. Noting this ambiguity, however, does not lead to any general insight about English language and usage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They don’t go to any location other than the library since W declined all offers “That sounds nice, BUT…”